# Import custom class to cocoapods section

Tags: ios, objective-c, import, cocoapods

Iam using cocoapods in my project and I have a class outside the pods section.
I need to import my class to the pod section but it shows an error that my class doesnt exist.Alsi i tried to use @class MyClass, but this didnt solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do such a thing?

If you want to customize the pod, I suggest you subclass the class in your own project and change methods or add functionality.

That way, you won't have to copy-paste your changes when you update/re-install pods.

Just a note, while subclassing methods, don't forget to call super.*nameOfTheMethod*()